# Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method

Tags: java, jsp, inheritance

I am receiveing the following errors when accessing a JSP which uses Java page after login:

Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method

The JSP Page extends another JSP page, which I didn't write but need to maintain, until we upgrade to JSF later. Below is the code for the page generating the error:

```
  <%
  @ page session="true"
  extends="common.JSPMain"
  import="services.*,
  %>

  <%
  MainPage thisPage = (MainPage)this.run(MainPage.class, pageContext);
  if (thisPage!=null) 
  {
  %>
  ....
```

I actually have this running locally (with java 7) but get the error with Java 8 perhaps something has changed with visibility between 7 and 8 also?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

***Update***

A error which appears in the logs when deploying/compiling relates to the Jersey version:

From looking around it may be a conflict between weblogic 12.2.1.3 and Jersey 1x. Tried using prefer web-inf classes which stops the initial message above of changing the servlet class but unfortunately still gives the errors with ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.

Comment: Maybe consider using JSF instead? JSP is old...

Comment: its an older application, currently just needs to be maintained unfortunately, eventually probably will be rewritten in JSF.

Comment: Do you have any idea what 'extends' actually means in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Its weird that the visibility has been changed sinds 8 (I doubt it, but could be mistaken).

What you could do is change the visibility through refelction

```
Field field = getField(MainPage.class, privateFieldName);
field.setAccessible(true);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately it didn't work and I'm now thinking it may be a conflict between Jersey and Weblogic 12.2.1.3. I was using weblogic 12.1.2 and the same jersey version fine. But am getting the following error when deploying/compiling <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.>